# How to properly overload global new function to create objects

Tags: c++, new-operator

I've seen a few places that show how to overload the global new function for allocations. What I would like to do is to have any call to 'new' call my function, which simply wraps the C++ standard 'operator new' and tracks memory usage. But I have a problem of not knowing how to construct the object because the type of the object is not available in the function:

```
void* operator new (std::size_t size)
{
       // I don't know what to construct
} 

struct MyClass{ int members[8];}

new MyClass;  // I'd basically like to wrap the standard 'new' function allocator.
```

Comment: You can overload `operator new` for your class only. Maybe this is what you actually want? See [section class specific overloads](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new).

Comment: Ah, seeing Remy's answer I note what you actually missed... Still you can do that on class base only, if this appears appropriate to you – again, only allocation necessary, constructor is called later.

Comment: You are confusing the `new operator` with `operator new`. Easily confused but only the `new operator` constructs objects, `operator new` just allocates memory, like `malloc`.

Answer (score 3):

You are not supposed to *construct* an object inside of an overloaded `operator new`, only *allocate* raw memory of the requested size and return a pointer to it. The object’s constructor will be called on the returned memory after the `operator new` exits.

A [`new` *expression*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) calls [`operator new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) specifying the size of the type, then calls the type’s constructor on that memory, and then returns a pointer to the object that was created.

Thus, an expression like `new MyClass` in your example is *roughly equivalent* (not exactly) to this:

```cpp
//MyClass *cls = new MyClass; 
void *mem = :: operator new (sizeof(MyClass));
MyClass *cls = static_cast<MyClass*>(mem);
cls->MyClass();
```

And the converse is true for the [`delete` *expression*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete), which calls the type’s destructor, and then calls [`operator delete`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete) to deallocate the raw memory, eg:

```cpp
//delete cls; 
cls->~MyClass();
:: operator delete (cls);
```

Comment: Would the last step be something equivalent to a placement new? So allocates memory with malloc (or something) - "void *mem = ::operator new (sizeof(MyClass));"  and then  placement new - " new(mem) MyClass();" ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're looking for a [Factory function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). A factory is a dedicated function (or even a class) that produced instances of a class.

E.g.

```cpp
#include <memory>

struct MyClass { int members[8]; };

std::unique_ptr<MyClass> MyClassFactory() {
    auto inst = std::make_unique<MyClass>();
    // assign some stuff to members
    return inst;
}
```